# Favorable properties for penalized likelihood estimators

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, regularization

I'm reading through Fan and Li's [SCAD](http://orfe.princeton.edu/~jqfan/papers/01/penlike.pdf) paper on Nonconcave Penalized
Likelihood. The idea is to penalize the loss function by $p_\lambda(\theta)$ where $\lambda$ can be some tuning parameter. Fan proposes that a proper penalty function should produce estimators with the following 3 properties, and also lists sufficient conditions for the penalty function to have these properties:

---

Unbiasedness: The resulting estimator is nearly unbiased when the true unknown parameter is large to avoid unnecessary modeling bias. A sufficient condition for unbiasedness is $ p_{\lambda}'(|\theta|)=0 $ for large $|\theta|$.

Sparsity: The resulting estimator is a thresholding rule, which automatically sets small estimated coefficient to zero to reduce model complexity. A sufficient condition for sparsity is $\min_{\theta \neq 0}\left\{|\theta| + p_{\lambda}'(|\theta|)\right\} > 0 $.

Continuity: The resulting estimator is continuous in data $z$ to avoid instability in model prediction. A sufficient and necessary condition for continuity is that the minimum of the function $|\theta| + p_{\lambda}'(|\theta|)$ is attained at 0.

---

It is the last one (continuity) that I don't quite understand how the condition stated results in a continuous estimator. Also Fan mentions:

A penalty function satisfying the conditions of sparsity and continuity must be singular at the origin.

I also can't grasp why this must be so.

Comment: See figure 3 in the paper.  If this condition is not met, then you can have multiple minimizers of (2.3) in the paper and thus the penalized estimator isn't really well defined or stable.  Conversely, if the conditon is satisfied, then $\theta+p_{\lambda}'(\theta)$ is a monotone function of $\theta>0$, and there's only one minimizer for each value of the data $z$.

Comment: By "singular", the author means "nondifferentiable."  The penalty function's derivative is bounded away from 0 on either side of $\theta=0$, and has opposite signs on the two sides, so the derivative can't be defined at $\theta=0$.